Data fusion 40.0 : Nested Fields Access on StructArray field not working
I have a parquet file with following example data:
{

  "a" : "A1",

 "myobjects" : 
  
[
          {
                  "name" : "1",
                  "value" : "V"
          },

         {
                   "name" : "2",
                   "value" :  "V2"
         }

  ]
}

When I am trying to access the subfield "name" none of the following syntax is working for me using latest datafusion package (40.*) and I am getting error as "Nested identifiers not yet supported".
Examples I tried:
SELECT myobjects.element.name FROM my_table;
SELECT myobjects.name FROM my_table;
SELECT myobjects.item.name FROM my_table;
SELECT myobjects["name"] FROM my_table;
From DF I tried
col("myobjects.name")
col("myobjects.item.name")
col("myobjects.element.name");
None of them worked for me, Can someone please help me understand what am I doing wrong ?
